# entitlements are not valid error in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, entitlements

I am having a weired problem.

while installing the adhoc ipa file to my ipad for testing purpose i am having a weired error message while syncing app through itunes.

The error is that The app can not be installed because the entitlements are not valid.

I m new bee dont know what is the issue.

I have added `Entitlement.plist` file as well and linked that in the project settings and also added the field `get-task-allow` into the `entitlement.plist` file with the `false` value. but could not find any solution.

My Old Build is working fine when i install it through itunes but new build is giving this error. What could be the reason please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing, make sure that your device UDID is added to provisioning profile.
2. Next is to make sure that you are using latest profile that you created and installed on your Mac.
3. Before building, make sure that you are selecting correct profile in build settings. Some time you might be having two profiles and you have to select proper one.
4. Make sure that your profile is still valid.

With latest XCode version, you don't need to have entitlements file at all.